# Call Axios with componentDidMount get request is in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

Axios starts making the GET request and never stops anymore when I add the following code to the component data. No changing on the state or no calling the setState method.

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react')
            .then(response => {
                alert(response.data);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use axios.get(), not axios():

```
        axios.get('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react')
            .then(response => {
                alert(response.data);
            });
```

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, it is axios.get, i think the problem is about NLog: axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000";

//Log, to work with NLog
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  request => {
    console.log(request);
    return request;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from using axios instance and NLog.